# Application subclass ClassNotFoundException (but only for some users)

Tags: android

Very weird error.

I released an update of an app and the vast majority had no trouble. But the AzureApplication is the Application object defined in the manifest, so if this was thrown it would crash instantly at launch so no one would be able to use it. Everyone is using the same app version but i received only 1 report of this exception below.

Why would it throw a ClassNotFoundException for this key class, but for 99% of people there is no problem??

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application azurewing.android.AzureApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: azurewing.android.AzureApplication
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:501)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:140)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1297)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: azurewing.android.AzureApplication
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:982)
    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:496)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: How is this Azure Application/class defined (where) and how is it used (where too)?

Comment: It is a subclass of android.app.Application. It is defined in the manifest like <application android:name="azurewing.android.AzureApplication" ... />

Comment: Ok, but what I meant is how do you include this library in your application - are you doing in this way -> http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject ?

Comment: Yes, the AzureApplication is in a project library. And yes that's how it's included. If it wasn't included properly it wouldn't work on any device.

Comment: Did you include this application in the manifest inside `<uses-library>`? Could you please paste the manifest too?